# How to use type instances in Agda?

Tags: agda

I know how to define typeclasses, and after reading the definition of `RawMonad`, `RawMonadZero`, `RawApplicative` and more, I implemented some simple type instances:

```
data Parser (A : Set) : Set where
  MkParser : (String → List (A × String)) → Parser A

ParserMonad : RawMonad Parser
ParserMonad = record {
    return = λ a → MkParser λ s → < a , s > ∷ []
  ; _>>=_  = λ p f → MkParser $ concatMap (tuple $ parse ∘ f) ∘ parse p
  }
```

But when I'm trying to use `ParserMonad.return` in the implementation of `ParserApplicative`, I failed:

```
ParserApplicative : RawApplicative Parser
ParserApplicative = record {
    pure = ParserMonad.return -- compile error
  ; _⊛_  = ...
  }
```

My question is: how to use `ParserMonad.return` to implement `ParserApplicative.pure`? How can I do that or what doc should I read?

Comment: Please try to submit [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, "I failed" is not very informative: if you got a compilation error, copy/paste it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you're not using instance arguments, you are using records. [Instance arguments](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/instance-arguments.html) are an independent mechanism which, combined with records, can be used to simulate something like type classes.

Coming back to records, to use the field `f` of a record `r` of type `R`, you can do various things:

- Use the projection `R.f` applied to `r`:

```
 a = R.f r
```

- Name `M` the module corresponding to the content `r` as an `R` and use the definition `f` in it:

```
module M = R r
a = M.f
```

- Open that module and use `f` directly:

```
open module R r
a = f
```

Using the first alternative, in your case it'd give us:

```
ParserApplicative : RawApplicative Parser
ParserApplicative = record {
   pure = RawMonad.return ParserMonad
   (...)
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. The last example is exactly what I wanted ;D